# How to smooth XY Co-ordinates of linear feature?

Tags: coordinate-system, vb.net, polyline-creation, line, smoothing

I need to smooth xy co-ordinates. see the image:

[image]

In this case, i need to remove 5,6,7,8 and 9th co-ordinates or need to make those co-ordinates  as a straight line between 4th and 5th. is there any logic to do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to *identify* the nodes to be removed or simply how to remove them once they have been identified?  The latter is so trivial I would presume you mean the former, but that brings up the crucial question: on what basis have you determined that these nodes *should* be removed? After all, they constitute more than half the length of this path, so arguably those nodes should be kept and nodes 0..3 and 11..14 should be removed instead!

Comment: @whuber I need to identify the nodes(5,6,7,8 and 9) to remove . Assume the average distance is 2m between the nodes from 0 to 4 and the average distance is 1m between the nodes from 10 to 14. but for 5 to 9 the average distance is too high (Ex: 10m).Like that i can determine that those nodes should be removed.But i'm not sure whether this logic is correct.

Comment: Based on the information you have given it is not possible to tell whether that logic is correct, Venkat. For instance, if the coordinates were obtained by a GPS at regular time intervals, then your rule would eliminate all nodes where the unit was moving the fastest!  More information is needed in order to resolve your question.

Comment: Yes the coordinates were obtained by a GPS at regular time intervals

Answer (score 2):

It doesen't seem to be smoothing but rather removing of outliers you are looking for. Maybe you will find some help in this discussion: [What algorithm should I use to remove outliers in trace data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19683/what-algorithm-should-i-use-to-remove-outliers-in-trace-data)