# open-source code for the map matching algorithm

Tags: python, javascript, algorithm, map-matching

For map matching of the GPS data to the network data, there is a algorithm from Schussler, N. & Axhausen, K. (2009a). 
Is this algorithm released under open-source license ? Where can I find this ?

"I know SF City implemented one of these algorithms to process gps tracks from a smart phone app they are using to track cyclists (cycletracks); and they released all of the code under an open-source license."- found in the below question.

[What algorithm should I use to remove outliers in trace data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19683/what-algorithm-should-i-use-to-remove-outliers-in-trace-data)

Comment: 'found in StackExchange' - better show us the link once you found it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try OSRM. It's a great open source library developed by Mapbox.

The function of OSRM includes: map-matching, routing, near, etc. All these operations are based on OpenStreetMap.

It supports both windows and unix-like system. But building OSRM form source on unix-like system is bit arduous. you can refer to [official site](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Building-OSRM) and [a great tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-osrm-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) to save your life.